# max-width: 100% not working on images with srcset

Tags: css, html, srcset

I have this:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Hola</h1>
  <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/tosov034h/small.png"
       srcset="http://s30.postimg.org/72ndi9pe9/large.png 1024w,
               http://s30.postimg.org/ybyqwrqhd/medium.png 640w,
               http://s30.postimg.org/tosov034h/small.png 320w"
       alt="owl">
</div>
```

I don't think this works on the snippet so, you can check it here: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/ZbOMNR

The thing is that when the 1024px image loads, I'd spect that `max-width: 100%` would start to work, and limit the image display with to the actual width  (1024px). That is not what happens, as it keeps growing, as it had `width:100%` instead and stops at 1200px wich is the max width of the wrapper.

Why is this not working? What should I do to limit size to the max size of the image to the max real size?

Comment: how about making `max-width` of wrapper to `width:1200px;` and `img{max-width:100%;`

Comment: don't mention any `width` or max-width` to either `img` tag or `wrapper` class. It'll load the image in actual size

Comment: @Rajeshkannan not working as you say. Also, what would happen if there is no support?

Answer (score 2):

You have omitted the `sizes` attribute, which is invalid. When omitted, it defaults to `100vw` so the image will have that width. If you want 100vw below 1024px and 1024px for wider viewports, you can do something like `sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 1024px, 100vw"`

Comment: Isn't that mixing stying with content distribution?

Comment: Kind of - but if you want the browser to show a variety of image files in a variety of different scenarios, you need to tell it what those scenarios are.

Comment: The reason it is like this is that browsers start downloading images ASAP -- before external CSS has been downloaded and parsed. So the intended size of the image has to be in the markup, or pages with responsive images would have a page loading penalty compared to `<img src>`, which is not acceptable.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to display image in 100% width,

then use

```
min-width:100%;
```